# ASP.NET MVC Dynamic External URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a site where users can supply a URL of their choice.

I'm sure it's a security hole so what should I do to tighten that down without losing too much flexability?

If I were to leave it, how could I render a link or build a route such that I could link users externally?
This doesn't work (of course):

```
<a href="@item.Location" target="_self">@item.Title</a>
```

Comment: Web browsers allow users to supply a URL of their choice too. :)

Comment: Agreed :) However, there is a business need to provide helpful links to people coming to this page.

Comment: The best place to ensure that user-provided URLs don't mess with the site is when validating input. This way, URIs like `javascript:alert("Wat!")` can be disallowed without removing the protocol-part of the URL. Users should have the freedom to choose between giving `http://` or `https://` URLs, for example.

Answer (score 7):

Append protocol before `@item.URL` like this:

```
<a href="http://@item.URL" target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
```